# Using an existing Azure installation as box for Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, azure, vagrant

We use an Ubuntu server hosted by Azure as our production environment. Recently I have been experimenting with Vagrant to simulate the production environment on our laptops. Does anyone know if it is possible to create an image of our Azure installation and use this as a box for Vagrant?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy option or a magic button to download an Azure image and use it a box for Vagrant but definitely there is a way to achieve that (not the magic button but the image for the box).

Azure use different providers to create and provision the vms used in it is infrastructure. In your case you mention that your team (or you) use an Ubuntu server on Azure. If the server was created from a third party image provider, like Bitnami LAMPStack, you can't directly from Azure download the image or even from Microsoft VM Depot. But you can use the image from the Bitnami website (if the case is that you use a Bitnami image) and download if from there.

To determine what image version use, tn the Azure portal you will see something like this:

[image: Azure portal]

And in the Bitnami website you will see the image used to create the virtual machine in Azure:

[image: Bitname vms list]
Now you can use the Bitnami image, which is basically the "same image" used to create the server on Azure. You will need to [convert into a Vagrant box](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes/base.html) and provisioned it with the same settings and apps used in your production system.